# If $\text{sgn}(Y-c) = \text{sgn}(Z-c)$ a.s., then $Y=Z$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables, with $Y \overset{d}{=} Z$, and $E|Y| < \infty$. If $\text{sgn}(Y-c) = \text{sgn}(Z-c)$ a.s., for all constant $c$, then I want to show that $Y = Z$ almost surely.

My idea is that if this does not hold, then there exists some positive measure set $B$, and $\epsilon > 0$, such that $|Y-Z| > \epsilon$ on $B$. Now, I want to basically pick $c$ strategically that I can find some positive measure subset of $B$ such that $Y-c < 0$, and $Z-c \geq 0$ on this subset, and then derive a contradiction.

I believe I can do this because $E|Y| < \infty$, but I am having trouble writing this down rigorously.

Is this approach feasible, and is there is any easy way to make this idea precise?

Comment: If $a,b$ are real numbers with the property that sgn$(a-c) = $ sgn$(b-c)$ for all $c \in \Bbb R$, then it necessarily follows that $a=b$ (because one can otherwise set $c:=\frac12(a+b)$ to obtain a contradiction). Why do you need the other assumptions?

Comment: Yes, of course, but these aren’t numbers - they’re random variables (functions). There is some subtlety to take care of with the global behaviour of the function and the “almost surely”. What you are saying here is definitely the idea if I deal with it pointwise, but I think I need to be a bit careful here when writing it down, since I can only choose $c$ once (for basically uncountably many $a$, $b$).

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see what you are saying about taking an uncountable intersection of events of full measure. This can be avoided because you really only need sgn$(a-c) = $ sgn$(b-c)$ for all $c \in \Bbb Q$, in order to deduce that $a=b$. This means that you only need to intersect over countably many events (indexed by rational numbers) of full probability, thus still obtaining an event of full probability.

Comment: @Shalop Yes, that makes perfect sense. Can’t believe I didn’t think of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point here is that the exceptional set depends on $c$. Clearly there is one set $E$ of probability $0$ such that $sgn(Y-c)=sgn(Z-c)$ for all rational numbers $c$ if $\omega \notin E$. Now if $\omega \notin E$ and $Y(\omega) >Z(\omega) $ then there is a rational number $c$ such that $Y(\omega) >c>Z(\omega) $. but this makes $Y(\omega)-c >0$ and $Z(\omega)-c <0$ a contradiction, Similarly, $Y(\omega) <Z(\omega) $ leads to a contradiction. Hence $Y(\omega) =Z(\omega) $ if $\omega \notin E$.